# Getting all values of column B for each value of column A in new data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with two columns. I would like to create a new data frame which lists all values of second column for each unique value of the first column in the first data frame. I do not want to use data tables.

After several trials and errors, I came up with the following. I would like to know if there is an easier (one-step?), faster, or more optimal way to achieve this, since the actual data frames I will be running this on are very large.

```
> df <- data.frame( a=c( 1, 1, 2, 2, 3 ), b=c( 6:10 ) );
> df
  a  b
1 1  6
2 1  7
3 2  8
4 2  9
5 3 10
> df2 <- data.frame( a=unique( df$a ) )
> temp <- dlply( df, .(a), function( x ) data.frame( bs=x$b ) );
> df2$bs <- lapply( temp, function( x ) x$bs )
> df2
  a   bs
1 1 6, 7
2 2 8, 9
3 3   10
>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aggregate(b ~ a, df, paste)

  a    b
1 1 6, 7
2 2 8, 9
3 3   10
```

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
 df%>%
   group_by(a)%>%
   summarise(bs=glue::collapse(b,","))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      a bs  
  <dbl> <chr>
1    1. 6,7  
2    2. 8,9  
3    3. 10
```

Answer (score 1):

A `base R` way

```
aggregate(b ~ a, df, FUN = toString)
#     a    b
#1    1 6, 7
#2    2 8, 9
#3    3   10
```

---

If  you want keep the entries numeric, perhaps try creating a list column.

```
(df_new <- aggregate(b ~ a, df, FUN = list))
#  a    b
#1 1 6, 7
#2 2 8, 9
#3 3   10

str(df_new)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ a: num  1 2 3
# $ b:List of 3
#  ..$ 1: int  6 7
#  ..$ 2: int  8 9
#  ..$ 3: int 10
```

Comment: Thanks, any way to do this without converting to character, i.e. keeping the list numeric?

Comment: Seems like Markus and I were doing almost the same. Anyway, if you want commas in the second column it can never be a numeric variable.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(b = toString(b)), by = a]
#   a    b
#1: 1 6, 7
#2: 2 8, 9
#3: 3   10
```